# Powershell Bitstransfer

Tags: powershell, bit

I just wanted to write a script, that automates file downloading for me, to keep the files up to date.

I can download .pdf,.txt and so on from different websites, but I can't manage to download an .exe from a specific website. Though I can download the .exe via my browser without any problems.

I start the script in the powershell(started as administrator). Then it says Connections, but it doesn't connect. So the progression bar, doesn't change. Then after a few seconds it stops and i get my prompt back.

It does create a file but it's 0b big.

This is my scrip:

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer 
Start-BitsTransfer -Source http://media.kaspersky.com/utilities/VirusUtilities/EN/rectordecryptor.exe `
-Destination S:\Programme\Antiviren\rector.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

The script works, it sound more like a permissions issue

Do you or the account ( if scheduled task) have write access to the folder S:\Programme\Antiviren\ 
also Check if folder is read only

Comment: Hey,thanks for your answer! So the script works for you? I do have full access on the folder, even tried to download it to my home directory. But it wont download. It just "creates" a file with 0b of size. When downloading another file, from another website to that folder, it works!

Comment: doesn't look like a permissions issue to me. @CM, try Start-BitsTransfer -Source http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1514-x64.exe `
-Destination C:\Users\Public  ...or whatever folder, just a FOLDER

Comment: Hey Jaqueline, thanks for your advice! It worked to download the file from 7zip, to just a folder. So i tried it with the other path from kaspersky, but it wouldnt work. Same again, it just creates the file with 0 byte.